# React dangerouslySetInnerHTML to render an iframe youtube embed from props?

Tags: javascript, iframe, reactjs

Anybody have any idea how to get this prop attribute to stringToHTML in React? Thanks in advance!

```
var Video = React.createClass({

getDefaultProps: function getDefaultProps() {

        return propsObj;
},

createMarkup: function() { 

    return {__html: {this.props.video}}; 
},

  render: function() {
    return (

      <div className="video-container no-controls" id="player" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Why did you put `{...}` around `{this.props.video}`? That's invalid JavaScript.

Comment: It would be amazing if that fixed it, but it didn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a reason why HTML injection in React has such a cumbersome API: its use is strongly discouraged.

It's not obvious why you would want to use HTML injection for something as straightforward as a YouTube video iframe. The markup for it is quite predictable.

I strongly urge you to rewrite it in JSX. Here's the code for a YouTube component I used in a recent project.

```
const YouTubeVideo = ({ id }) => (

    <div className="youtube-wrapper">
        <div className="youtube">
            <iframe
                className="youtube-frame"
                src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}?autoplay=1`}
                allowFullScreen
            />
        </div>
    </div>

);
```

Comment: Thank you, David! That's what I needed. I was just trying to figure out the React way for a user to embed a youtube video from a backend.

Comment: Just for completion, you could just add the way to call/invoke this Component. Thanks for the code.

Comment: but this doesn't work with the Youtube iframe API (which has nice interfaces for manipulation)? Or am i mistaken; thanks!